# Creating a copy of a list of dictionaries with a subset of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

In python I have a list of dictionaries that all have the same keys, like this:

```
[
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to split this into two different list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'lunch_menu': ...,
    },
    ...
]

[
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    {'restaurant': ...,
      'dinner_menu': ...,
    },
    ...
]
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking I could copy the primary list twice and loop through each of the copies, running `pop()` on the key I don't want. But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial data used for both examples:

```
lst = [{'restaurant':'one_rest', 'lunch_menu':'one_lunch', 'dinner_menu':'one_din'},
       {'restaurant':'two_rest', 'lunch_menu':'two_lunch', 'dinner_menu':'two_din'}]
```

A clear, but non-Pythonic method:

```
one = []
two = []
for dic in lst:
    one.append({'restaurant' : dic['restaurant'],
                'lunch_menu' : dic['lunch_menu']})
    two.append({'restaurant' : dic['restaurant'],
                'dinner_menu' : dic['dinner_menu']})
```

More Pythonic:

```
one = [{k: dic[k] for k in ('restaurant', 'lunch_menu')} for dic in lst]
two = [{k: dic[k] for k in ('restaurant', 'dinner_menu')} for dic in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your dict and extract required subdict.

For Python versions 2.7 or later:

```
x = [
    {'restaurant': 1,
     'lunch_menu': 1,
     'dinner_menu': 1,
     },
    {'restaurant': 2,
     'lunch_menu': 2,
     'dinner_menu': 2,
     },
    {'restaurant': 3,
     'lunch_menu': 3,
     'dinner_menu': 3,
     },

]

print [{k: el[k] for k in ('restaurant', 'lunch_menu')} for el in x]
>>> [{'lunch_menu': 1, 'restaurant': 1}, {'lunch_menu': 2, 'restaurant': 2}, {'lunch_menu': 3, 'restaurant': 3}]
```

Otherwise:

```
print [{k: el[k] for k in ('restaurant', 'lunch_menu')} for el in x]
```